# Rotate object a object in 2D space

Tags: math, javafx, 2d, formula

I'm looking for solution to rotation a object in 2D space. I have Point in 
coordinates X, Y. I need move this object around object in the center in some distance. [Here is a picture with description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxoaX.png) I'm using java FX. I need some 
formular to this. Probably I have to use some sin and cos to turning but I do not know how. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a [`Rotate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/transform/Rotate.html) to the list of transforms for the object you are rotating:

```
double x = /* x-coordinate for center of rotation */ ;
double y = /* y-coordinate for center of rotation */ ;
double angle = /* angle in degrees */ ;

Rotate rotate = new Rotate(angle, x, y);
nodeToRotate.getTransforms().add(rotate);
```

The coordinates for the center of the rotation must be in the same coordinate system as used by the node you are rotating.

Comment: @TomášZachoval I think the answer provided by James_D is much more straightforward and easier :)

Comment: Yes thank you both, I belive so. But I'dont know how it use.  Have I crete a new method in class ship? Because I can not use getTransform() to ship and I dont know why?

Comment: @TomášZachoval If you want to have `getTransforms()` for your ship, you need to make your ship a type of `Node`, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43446139/4666747)

Answer (score 0):

When you rotate the vectors `(x,y)`(The line joining the center and the dot)
The new coordinate would be `(x',y')` and are related by

`x'= x*cos(angle)-y*sin(angle)`

`y'= x*sin(angle)+y*cos(angle)`

since here the y coordinate is upside down (i.e positive downwards) you'll have to replace `y`with `-y`

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply but it still does not work. I have a object called ship. It have coord X and coord Y. I need  my object rotate through an angle of XY a center.  Center object coord are X 300 and Y 300.

Comment: Since center is shifted from (0,0) to (300,300), replace both `x` and `y` with `(x-300)` and `(y-300)`, now since y-axis is inverted it becomes `(300-y)`

Comment: @TomášZachoval As in my answer, all you need is `ship.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(angle, 300, 300));`.

Comment: I'm sory but 'm probably to slow to understand. Could you halp me with code please?
   public static void turnVithShip(ForeginShip ship, double dgr) {
        double x = ship.getPicture().getLayoutX()+338;
        double y = ship.getPicture().getLayoutY()+308;

        double nx = x * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(dgr)) - y * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(dgr));
        double ny = x * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(dgr)) + x * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(dgr));
        ship.getPicture().setLayoutX(nx);
        ship.getPicture().setLayoutY(ny);
}